# queryParams in Angular 2 being encoded, how do I prevent this from happening?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a link in Angular 2 which looks like this:

```
<a routerLink="/summary" queryParams="x=1">Ref. ID</a>
```

I expect this to resolve to

> summary?x=1

Instead it resolves to:

> /summary?0=x&1=%3D&2=1

Which is not what I want at all.

Whenever I inject **ActivatedRouteSnapshot** into a component and take a look at the **queryParams** property, it is an object containing 3 strings, one for each character:

[image: Screenshot]

Obviously I am missing something obvious, could somebody point me in the right direction? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use binding `[]` for the `queryParams`

```
<a routerLink="/summary" [queryParams]="{x : 1}">Ref. ID</a>
```

That will probably work better :)

Answer (score 2):

As per [RouterLink directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html) you have to set it as below :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/summary']" [queryParams]="{x:1}">Ref. ID</a>
```